# matplotlib symlog malfunctions when using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Plotting with a symmetric log scale using pandas gives excessively wide axis limits.

Set up some dummy data and make a plot:

```
>>> x = [0, 1]
>>> y = [-11825.251019, -470.310618]
>>> plt.plot(x, y)
>>> plt.yscale('symlog')
>>> plt.ylim()
(-13894.13926670043, -400.27964366818765)
```

So far, so good. Now try the same thing with pandas:

```
>>> pd.Series(y).plot()
>>> plt.yscale('symlog')
>>> plt.ylim()
(-12392.998039049999, 97.43640205000008)
```

Why is the upper axis limit *positive*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Series.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) has the `logy` parameter, and using `logy='sym'` produces the same ylimits as pure matplotlib.

```
pd.Series(y).plot(logy='sym')
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if this is a "right answer" or a workaround, though.

Comment: I would say using the pandas api is the right answer.